# How do I create image roll over nav buttons in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

It's easy enough in Wordpress to create a nav bar based off wp_list_pages and wp_list_categories. But these output text, and you can't effect each output li in a different way.

I know I can manually create the nav bar, but is there a good way to replace the wp_list_ output with images?

Answer (score 2):

Just alter your CSS to display the images as backgrounds to the li elements and the anchors as block elements. For best usability, set the text-indent in your anchors to something line -9999px.

To better understand how to select and style the nav list and its elements, read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_list_pages#Markup_and_styling_of_page_items).

Comment: The problem is that each li will need a different image – making CSS impossible if the links are generated though wp_list_